# Show a triangle below selected menu item

Tags: html, css

I'd like to show a little triangle (similar as my tag box) below the selected menu item. I've tried various things without success, see http://jsfiddle.net/7zRVU/1/ 
How could I do that? Many thanks

```
nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
    margin-right: -4px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    }
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
nav a {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1) !important ; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;

}


nav a:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35) !important ; 
}
.activeNav {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35) !important ; 
}
nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;

    background: none;
    padding-top: 5px
}
nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9) !important ; 
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33) !important ; 
    padding: 10px
}
nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: rgba(20,150,220,0.5) !important ; 
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
.hover a {
    display: block;
}
.hover span {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    background: rgba(20,150,220,0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0 0 -57px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
}

li.selected a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(16,65,145,0.9);

}


li.selected a:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-top-color: #3A7CDB;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}


.tagbox {
  top: -10px;
  left: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3A7CDB;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #518CDE, #3A7CDB);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
        margin-top:140px;

}

.tagbox:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-top-color: #3A7CDB;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this CSS solution: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ , also, http://cssarrowplease.com/ .Rgds,

Comment: Thanks. The issue is not to create the triangle, as you can see on my fiddle there is one on the tag box, the issue is to place it under the selected menu item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an update to your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7zRVU/4/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/7zRVU/4/)

You have actually done it, but you just need a "position:relative;" to your "selected" class, so the arrow to be absolutely positioned with it, and then, just change the position of the arrow to "top: height of the selected item"

```
.selected {
    position: relative;
}

li.selected a:after {
  top: 23px;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-top-color: #3A7CDB;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```